# The in Operator, numbers are converted to string

Tags: javascript

I am learning about the in operator.

```
var data = [7,8,9];
"0" in data // => true: array has an element "0"
1 in data   // => true: numbers are converted to strings
3 in data   // => false: no element 3
```

I understand how "0" is an element in the data (7). 
How is "1 in data" => true?? with that logic "3 in data" should be true as well since "number are converted to strings.

EDIT: Okay. I see it now... -**_**-

Source: Javascript the Definitive Guide by O'Reilly.

Comment: `no element at index 3` :)

Comment: and no element 1 in that array

Comment: @user3223207: `data[1]`? ;)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: I followed the link and read it. Still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user3223207 - Oops wrong link. That one was for `for(key in obj)`. This one is for just the `in` keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thank you! The link will be bookmarked for future references!

Comment: all keys are strings in js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 in data`
This is checking if there is an element present at index `1`
**8 exists at index 1**

`3 in data`
This is checking if there is an element present at index `3`
**There is nothing at index 3** (the index goes from 0 to 2)

Comment: Ooooooooooooh I feel dumb now -.-. Thank you :). My only excuse would be: haven't taken a break for 4 hours while learning and practicing JS code.

Comment: ;) I don't blame you, it threw me of also

Answer (score 0):

If you try to iterate array  like :

`for (a in data) console.log(a)`

you'll see 0,1,2

this is how array works.  it wont be the same for iterating object properties.

those are the indexes .

Comment: @downvoter  , any explanation ?

Comment: Thank you Royi! I will write that in my notes. Definitely helps when you have larger arrays. :)